# WaitAll for tasks from dictionary and get result, including Dictionary key

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, asynchronous, task

I have to modify the following code. I have given a list of tasks (httpClient.Run method returns Task). I have to run them and wait until all of them are done. Later on I need to collect all results and build response.

```
var tasks = new Dictionary<string, Task<string>>();
tasks.Add("CODE1", service.RunTask("CODE1"));
tasks.Add("CODE2", service.RunTask("CODE2"));
tasks.Add("CODE3", service.RunTask("CODE3"));
//...

var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Values); // how to get CODE (dictionary KEY) here
// build response
```

The problem above is that when we get `results` we have lost exactly which task was run. results is string array, but I need, for instance,`KeyValuePair array`. We need to know which task (CODE) was run, so that we can build result properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async` in a Select lambda to transform the `KeyValuePair<T1, Task<T2>`s into `Task<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>>`s.

```
var resultTasks = tasks.Select(async pair => KeyValuePair.Create(pair.Key, await pair.Value));
IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> results = await Task.WhenAll(resultTasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do it. This is written assuming you do the `Task.WhenAll()` call first. Otherwise, you'll block the thread when you start to enumerate over `resultsWithKeys`.

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Values());
var resultsWithKeys = tasks.Select(
    x => new
    {
        Key = x.Key, 
        Result = x.Value.Result
    });

foreach (var result in resultsWithKeys)
    Console.WriteLine($"{result.Key} - {result.Result.SomeValue}");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Dictionary<string, Task<string>>` contains tasks that do not propagate the key as part of their [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result). If you prefer to have tasks that include the key in their result, you'll have to create a new dictionary and fill it with new tasks that wrap the existing tasks. The `TResult` of these new tasks can be a struct of your choice, for example a [`KeyValuePair<string, string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2). Below is an extension method `WithKeys` that allows to create easily the new dictionary with the new tasks:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, Task<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>> WithKeys<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, Task<TValue>> source)
{
    return source.ToDictionary(e => e.Key,
        async e => KeyValuePair.Create(e.Key, await e.Value.ConfigureAwait(false)),
        source.Comparer);
}
```

Usage example:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string>[] result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.WithKeys().Values);
```